# BeanInstantiationException in Spring Boot with local @Configure and XML Configure for 3rd party

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app with my own `GlobalConfig` class.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class GlobalConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap.servers}")
    private String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS;

    @Value("${kafka.schema.registry}")
    private String SCHEMA_REGISTRY;

.. etc
```

This app includes a 3rd party Spring Boot app that uses an XML config. The 3rd party app creates its own `ApplicationContext` using an XML file in the main app's `resources` directory.

The problem is, during this 3rd party `ApplicationContext`'s `refresh()`, it references my local `GlobalConfig` and complains that it can't resolve the placeholders. And then it fails to instantiate.

So, how do I remove my `GlobalConfig` from the 3rd party's `AppContext`'s bean factory so this exception isn't thrown?

> o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext   : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'broadcast' defined in class path resource
> [context/broadcast.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate
> [org.foo.ThirdPartyBean]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'globalConfig': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
> 'bootstrap.servers' in value "${kafka.bootstrap.servers}"

Answer (score 0):

just try to import xml file in GlobalConfig

```
@ImportResource("classpath:context/broadcast.xml")
```

Comment: Didn't work. Same issue.

Comment: your application.property have this property kafka.bootstrap.servers